# Argument of type "HMODULE" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*"

Tags: c++

I am rather new to c++, and I am struggling to initialize a hook in my game hack. On the line where I am attempting to pattern scan a DLL from the game's files, I am getting the error in the title, they will be marked. If any more code needs to be provided LMK, I appreciate any help.

Code:

```
void hooks::initialize() {

const auto create_move_target = reinterpret_cast<void*>(get_virtual(interfaces::clientmode, 24));
const auto paint_traverse_target = reinterpret_cast<void*>(get_virtual(interfaces::panel, 41));
const auto lock_cursor_target = reinterpret_cast<void*>(get_virtual(interfaces::surface, 67));

original_wnd_proc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(SetWindowLongPtrA(FindWindowA("Valve001", nullptr), GWL_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG>(menu::wnd_proc)));

if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to initialize MH_Initialize.");

if (MH_CreateHook(lock_cursor_target, &surface::lock_cursor, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&lock_cursor_original)) != MH_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to initialize lock_cursor. (outdated index?)");

MH_CreateHook(**reinterpret_cast<void***>(utilities::pattern_scan(GetModuleHandleA("gameoverlayrenderer.dll"), "FF 15 ? ? ? ? 8B F8 85 FF 78 18") + 2), &menu::reset, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&reset_original)); //error at GetModuleHandleA

MH_CreateHook(**reinterpret_cast<void***>(utilities::pattern_scan(GetModuleHandleA("gameoverlayrenderer.dll"), "FF 15 ? ? ? ? 8B F8 85 DB") + 2), &menu::present, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&present_original)); //error at GetModuleHandleA

if (MH_CreateHook(create_move_target, &create_move::hook, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&create_move_original)) != MH_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to initialize create_move. (outdated index?)");

if (MH_CreateHook(paint_traverse_target, &paint_traverse::hook, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&paint_traverse_original)) != MH_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to initialize paint_traverse. (outdated index?)");

if (MH_EnableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS) != MH_OK)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to enable hooks.");

console::log("[setup] hooks initialized!\n");
```

}

Comment: What is `utilities::pattern_scan` and what does it expect as its first argument?

Comment: it expects a char*
heres the code:
std::uint8_t* pattern_scan(const char* module_name, const char* signature) noexcept;

Comment: Then pass it a `char*`! Why are you passing it the result of `GetModuleHandleA`?

Comment: I fixed the problem. utilities::pattern_scan should have actually been calling for a void* as its first argument, not a char*. I appreciate the help though. :)

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<void*>` (almost?) never makes sense. Conversion of object pointers to `void*` is implicit, and any other conversions are undefined and should be performed with care, if at all. And `void***` … just don’t.